# Segmentation fault in MPI_Isend

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm trying to write an MPI program using a defined library. I have a manager and multiple workers. The main function creates a derived data type and manager sends it to worker. I get the following error in `MPI_Isend` function. I track the error using `gdb`. The error is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memmove_ssse3_back () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-back.S:2577
2577   ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-back.S: No such file or directory
```

The program contains a `main.cpp` file with:

```
MPI_Aint extent ;
MPI_Datatype string_type; 
MPI_Datatype old_types[2] = {MPI_CHAR, MPI_INT};
int blocklen[2] = {NBR_ELEMENT,2} ;
MPI_Aint disp[2], base,member ;

base_string* str_data = new base_string(NBR_ELEMENT);
disp[0] = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(str_data->get_data()) - reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(str_data) ;
disp[1] = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(str_data->get_length()) - reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(str_data) ;

MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blocklen, disp, types, &string_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&string_type);
```

`base_string` is in another library which has 3 elements. Its class contains following functions:

```
inline const char*   get_data( void ) const;
inline       void    set_data( char* data, int32_t length = -1 );
inline       int32_t get_length( void ) const;

char*   _data;
int32_t _length;
int32_t _nb_blocks;
```

In `manager.cpp` contains `MPI_Isend` where I get the error:

```
base_string* str_dna = new base_string(NBR_ELEMENT);
str_dna->set_data(data,NBR_ELEMENT);
MPI_Request request;
MPI_Status stat;
printf("SENDING data %s \n",str_dna->get_data());
MPI_Isend(str_dna, 1,string_type, 1, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
```

Comment: Just allocate several different instances of `base_string` and check the values of `instance->get_data() - (const char *)instance`. Are they all the same of do some (or all) of them differ? Why? Also `get_length()` probably returns the value of the `_length` member and not a pointer to it.

Comment: For `get_length()`, i added `&` in `disp[1] = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&str_data->get_length())` to get the adress but it gives me the compilation error : `error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`

Comment: You are trying to get the address of the non-reference function return value - that doesn't work. You should provide a different class method that returns pointer to the value. But your bigger problem is how you should treat `_data`.

Comment: I created a new `base_string` instance and get displacements for it. The displacement values are different between two instances? Is it normal?

Comment: It is normal since both the object and its `_data` member are allocated on the heap and can end up at entirely unpredictable distances from one another. You have to rethink the structure of the object. Otherwise, the MPI datatype as created using one instance of `base_string` is in 99.9% of the cases unusable with other instances of the class.